# Main thread exception handler in Groovy script

Tags: exception, groovy

Having a problem with Groovy, I need to do some clean-up before exiting if uncaught exception was thrown in script, but can't find a way to do that.

I've tried *Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler*, but seems it's not working for the main thread. Then, I have had a look stack trace, which lead me to GroovyStarter where I found that nice piece of code, which means that *Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler* is not really supposed to work:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   try {
       rootLoader(args);
   } catch (Throwable t) {
       t.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

just for the sake of example here is what I want to archive (this is not runnable script, just to show the concept):

```
def process = new ProcessBuilder(command).redirectErrorStream(true).start();

onException = {
    process.destroy()
}
```

Please, do not suggest to use try/catch, that's something I can think of myself :)

PS: I'm a newbie to Groovy, so could be missing some obvious stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [add a shutdown hook](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/01/groovy-goodness-add-shutdownhook.html), which will always run (if possible) when the program exits:

```
def process = new ProcessBuilder(command).redirectErrorStream(true)

boolean success = false

def cleanup = {
    success = true
    process.destroy()
}

addShutdownHook {
    if(!success && process) {
        cleanup()
    }
}

process.start()
// alternatively, always rely on the shutdown hook
cleanup()
```

Note that the shutdown hook *always* runs, even if the program exits cleanly, so you would need to have some way of tracking that you ran your cleanup already if you want to clean up your connections early.

You can also have as many shutdown hooks as you want, so this could be used inside a function if you have multiple things to clean up.